# How exactly can I center this strong of code?

Tags: html, css

I have what probably is a very basic question, but I just can't seem to figure this one out. How can I center the submit button in this code that is labeled "lit".

```
</p>
    <!--
    <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90"<?php checked( ! empty( $_POST['rememberme'] ) ); ?> /> <?php esc_attr_e( 'Remember Me', 'password-protected' ); ?></label></p>
    -->

                <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Lit', 'password-protected' ); ?>" tabindex="100" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="password-protected" value="login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'password_protected_after_login_form' ); ?>
```

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You asked to:

- "center this strong of code"
- AND "How can I center the submit button"

I'm not sure which one you're asking, but here's a solution for both:

If you're looking to center the text, then you can use the CSS `text-align` property:

```
input#wp-submit {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you're trying to center the button, you can set its `margin` to:

```
input#wp-submit {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

**Edit**: By request, if you don't know how to use this CSS, simply add the following `<style>` tag into your `<head>` tag:

```
<style>
    /* Enter the appropriate code from above (style) here */
</style>
```

Comment: I do need help with the second option; button alignment. 

The only problem I have is, where exactly do I place the code you provided me?

Comment: @DanHarvey give me a moment: I'll provide an example. Do you understand CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you to center the button by using a div to wrap the button.
**CSS**

```
#d{
   width:100%;
}

input#wp-submit{
   margin-left:47%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="d">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Login" />
</div>
```